IP connectivity between hosts with different bit rates
I have two servers with applications that need to exchange IP traffic. Server A has a 1GE NIC while server B has 10GE NIC. Server B is also serving other computers, so it needs to stay 10G and server A cannot be upgraded to be 10G. I assume that connecting them to the same L2 switch in the same vlan is not a good idea because then server A might drop packets.
I can create two separate vlans and a virtual router to join them. However I do not expect this to solve the problem, correct?
What is the best practice to handle these kind of mixed configurations?

You are overthinking. Hosts communicate across different link rates all the time. A simple switch is sufficient to adapt different bit rates by buffering.
For most higher volume connections, TCP is used in the transport layer. TCP provides flow control and congestion control, so most likely there's nothing to worry about.
TCP's mechanisms cause a slight packet drop but at the same time they take care of retransmitting lost segments.
So, unless you have a very specific application that does not use TCP or a similar protocolm for transport, mismatching link rates between nodes doesn't cause any problems.

The VLAN does not matter because frames are going to get dropped going to the 1 Gbps server if they exceed 1 Gbps going to that switch interface. It is not the server that will drop packets, it is the switch interface that will drop any traffic exceeding its capabilities. The 1 Gbps switch interface getting 10 Gbps of traffic to send out the interface will drop frames because it can only send them out at 1 Gbps. Switches do not have large buffers, and frames get dropped all the time.
You mix-and-match interface speeds all the time. It is unlikely that the host of the 10 Gbps server have 10 Gbps interfaces, and the hosts and server still communicate. Dropped frames are very common on network switches, and you never really notice it unless the over-subscription is very unbalanced.
Think about your 10 Gbps server. If a request from a 1 Gbps host comes to it and it generates a bunch of 10 Gbps frames directed back to the 1 Gbps host, it is most likely that some of those frames get dropped.

Does this answer mean that the problem of dropped frames cannot be avoided in this configuration?

You will always have dropped frames. Even if both servers were at the same speed, you still drop frames. That is the nature of switching. It happens all the time. Upper-layer protocols deal with it. TCP is built to deal with lost segments, and application-layer protocols deal with lost UDP datagrams or they are just lost. Other transport protocols have a method to deal with it or rely on application-layer protocols. Real-time protocols do not want to recover lost datagrams, they just move on.

Ultimately you're worried about dropping packets because your server with a 1 gigabit link is 100% utilized. But even if both servers had 1 gigabit links, and you used them at 100% of capacity, you will have dropped packets so really it makes no difference. If you need exactly 1 gigabit or more than 1 gigabit, you will have dropped packets unless you upgrade the server from 1 gigabit to 10 gigabit so you have capacity for more than you will actually use. If you don't need 1 gigabit of capacity then you won't have dropped packets because the 1 gigabit link will have excess capacity.

@FrameHowitzer I see your point. So let’s assume I have the 1GE link utilized at most 80%, then the server B sends a UDP packet. The switch has the capacity to forward it to server A and so will not be dropped. Did I get your point?

@Ang Since the "80%" utilization is usually averaged over a period of time, there may be shorter periods with 100% utilization. If the ingress at those periods exceeds what the port can transmit plus the (tiny) buffering within the switch then you still have some packet loss.

Yeah, it's fine. If the average use is 80% (on graphs or whatever) then you probably want to upgrade to the next speed anyway if possible. It's like if you buy a car and drive it at 80% of the maximum RPM of the engine all day, then you obviously need something with more horsepower for whatever you are doing with that car. :)
Then again, the switch and network card don't care if you use 100% of link speed and have to restransmit a few frames now and then because of congestion. You're getting all your data and it's at peak 'efficiency' because you're not leaving any link speed unused.
